# Javascript: function in setTimeout and references

Tags: javascript, parameters, settimeout

I have an issue with a function call in setTimeout in a loop.
The parameters passed to the function are the last values computed in the loop for each iteration, please see example below.

```
for(var i=0; i<datesYM.length; ++i) {
    console.log(datesYM[i]);
    var dateYM = datesYM[i];
    setTimeout(function() {
        myDB.markMonthsValuesAsUpdated2(myDoctorId, dateYM)
    }, Math.floor(Math.random()*5001));
}

myDB.markMonthsValuesAsUpdated2 = function(myDoctorId, dateYM) {
    console.log(dateYM);
    [...]
```

Prints:

> 2012-01
>  2012-02
>  2012-03
>  2012-04
>   2012-05
>  2012-06
>  2012-07
>
> 2012-07
>  2012-07
>  2012-07
>  2012-07
>  2012-07
>   2012-07
>  2012-07

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the body in its own self-executing function to force a new scope:

```
for(var i=0; i<datesYM.length; ++i) {
    console.log(datesYM[i]);
    var dateYM = datesYM[i];
    (function(dateYM) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            myDB.markMonthsValuesAsUpdated2(myDoctorId, dateYM)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random()*5001));
    })(dateYM);
}
```

Without this, every function created in the loop closes over the *same instance* of `dateYM`, which has the value of the last iteration by the time any of those functions execute. Since JavaScript has function scope, the wrapper function creates a new `dateYM` on each iteration, so that each new function passed to `setTimeout` has its own instance.

Answer (score 1):

Create variable scope via a function that creates and returns the timeout handler.

```
function create_timeout_handler(myDoctorId, dateYM) {
    return function() {
        myDB.markMonthsValuesAsUpdated2(myDoctorId, dateYM)
    };
}
```

Then invoke that function and pass it whatever needs to be scoped.

```
setTimeout( create_timeout_handler(myDoctorId, dateYM), Math.floor(Math.random()*5001));
```

---

This is because every function you were giving to `setTimeout` was being created in the same variable scope, so they were all referencing the same `dateYM` variable, which was being overwritten in the loop.

Passing `dateYM` to another function that creates and returns the handler ensure that each handler is referencing the `dateYM` variable that was unique to each invocation of `create_timeout_handler`.