# trigger.io file.saveURL and looping

Tags: image, loops, save, trigger.io

I am using the file.saveURL in a loop and its working good but I am seeing some strage things. Basically I loop over about 70 images and then grab the uri to them after they are saved and store that locally so I can then use it to display in the app

What happens is that once the loop is done I display the images out but randomly some of the images are the same. I have validated the correct URL is being passed but its as if and I don't know for sure but maybe the function is not done with the previous and is somehow overwriting it?

This makes the most sence because the issue usually happens with images right next to each other.

So I guess my question is, does the file.saveURL only work on a one to one aspect, like it has to by synchronous?

If that is the case what would be the recommended approach for looping over and saving these images.

Thanks!

EDIT

This is a basic sample (I have some conditional stuff in there but this is the main part)

I have the JSON object stored and I loop over it

```
$(data).each(function(i){

        var slcval = 'speaker' + this.SID;
        var imageID = 'simageid' + this.IMAGE;
        var  speakerImage = "http://mydomain.com/users/images/speakers/" + this.IMAGE;

//then I call the save url function 
        saveURLImage(speakerImage,slcval,'speaker',this.SID,imageID);
}
```

this loops over my images and calls the save image function that then does the save URL function

```
function saveURLImage(url,ID,type,extraVal,imageID){
forge.file.saveURL(url, function (file) {
       forge.file.URL(file, function (url) {
        var fileObject = JSON.stringify(url);

        localStorage.setItem(ID, fileObject);


        })
        });
 }
```

This is a simple version of it, I have some other parts that set some localstorage vars but this is the main call.

Comment: Code to reproduce the problem would be helpful - both the code used for saving URLs and displaying the images afterwards would be great!

Comment: I'm wondering now if it might be how the files are saved, because it uses epoch date for the file name but only to the second, so what happens if two items are called at the same second?

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I've recreated this myself now, I think you might be right about the timing issue. Should be able to get a fix in for the not too distant future! It sounds like below that you've accidentally worked around this (possibly with a setTimeout?).

Comment: I thought it was a scope issue but I'm now convinced its a timeing issue because of what I have seen in the console . If you do put a fix in can you add an option to use your own name for the file? My files come down with unique names etc, having this option would be nice

Answer (score 1):

So my problem was a scoping issue

so if anyone else comes arrocss this I found this thred that helped out

[Javascript: function in setTimeout and references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824370/javascript-function-in-settimeout-and-references)

Basically what I did was creat a function that has an announmous function in it so the scope would be correct

function saveURLImage(url,ID,type,extraVal,imageID) {
    (function() {
        saveURLImageScoped(url,ID,type,extraVal,imageID)
    })();
    }

so the function name is still the same as before but I renamed the main function saveURLImageScoped and now it has its own variable scope